# Arduino to Arduino Communication using HC05

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, communication

I have been working on a project for work ( I'm a waiter :/ ) I was tasked to build a food wait time display that receives input from the kitchen and echoes the time via bluetooth to another display.
So that we are all on the same page I will describe what I have built and where I am stuck.

**Before I do, I would like to state that I have:**

- been planning and prototyping this thing for over a month
- googled/crawled all over the web looking for answers
- read the entire manual on the HC05 module
- Bound both of the bluetooth modules via AT commands One as Master the  other as Slave

Now with that out out the way here is what I have so far:

- 2x Arduino uno R3
- 2x 16x2 LCD Display
- 2x HC05 Bluetooth Modules (1 set as Master the other as Slave & bound using AT Commands)
- 2x 10K Potentiometers for adjusting the contrast
- 3x Momentary push Button switches on Master with pull-up resistors (timeUp, timeDown, sendButton)

Here is where I am stuck. **UPDATE**

I was able to get the master and slave to communicate. RX and TX on master were crossed... SMH! However now the issue is that the slave is *writing* both digits it receives on top of itself. First writing one digit then clearing it and then the second digit...

Enough with the prologue here is the a code:

**Master**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); //sets up LCD pins
int waitTime = 10; //if food comes quicker than there is no need for a display ;)
const int timeUp = 6; 
const int timeDown = 7;
const int sendButton = 8;
int timeUpState = 0;
int timeDownState = 0;
int sendButtonState = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(timeUp, INPUT);
  pinMode(timeDown, INPUT);
  pinMode(sendButton, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("  Sam Kullman's"); //Splash screen on start up
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("      Diner"); //Splash Screen
  delay(2000);        // Delay intended to allow the device to pair prior to use.
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Essen Dauert:"); //German for "Food takes":
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("   Minuten"); // xx minutes
  }

void loop(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  timeUpState = digitalRead(timeUp);
  timeDownState = digitalRead(timeDown);
  sendButtonState = digitalRead(sendButton);
  if (timeUpState == LOW) {
  waitTime += 5;
  delay(500);  //debounce button
  lcd.print(waitTime);
  }

  if(waitTime > 90){ // Max limit for wait time
    waitTime = 10;   //default wait time
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Essen Dauert:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("   Minuten");   
   }

 if (timeDownState == LOW){
  waitTime -= 5;
  delay(500);
  lcd.print(waitTime);
  }

  if(waitTime < 10){ //Min value waiting time
    waitTime = 10;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Essen Dauert:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("   Minuten");
   }

  if(Serial.available()){  // **This is where I am stuck** 
   if(sendButtonState == LOW){
   Serial.write(waitTime);
   delay(500);
  } 
 }  
}
```

**Slave**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("  Sam Kullman's");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("      Diner");
  }

void loop(){

  if (Serial.available()) {
   int waitTime = Serial.read();
    delay(200);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Essen Dauert:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.write(waitTime);
    lcd.print(" Minuten");
     }
  }
```

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: You'll might need debouncing here...

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Is the `delay(500);` after the state change not enough or in the wrong place? After some web crawling on "_debouncing_" I'm pretty sure I have denounced the buttons, or are you suggesting I take a hardware approach to denounce the buttons? I don't have an oscilloscope so I can't see exactly how the buttons are behaving.

Comment: no need for a hardware approach not a scope. If someone is trying to add 20 minutes, they are going to push it very fast, not every half of a second. You're going to miss some of the presses. There are some software libraries that I would consider if that's too big of an issue. Yes, it helps with debouncing, but it isn't the most ideal situation.

Comment: What libraries are you referring too?

Comment: something like [Bounce](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce)

Comment: any reason NOT to use the I2C bus for master/slave communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was reading the incoming serial data.

After changing `int waitTime = Serial.read()`

to `int waitTime = Serial.parseInt()`
the code works.

**Thanks to everyone for all your help and tips!**

Answer (score 0):

```
lcd.write(waitTime);
```

This line prints a single byte, whose (ASCII) value is the number in waitTime. You probably should write:

```
lcd.print(waitTime);
```

instead, which prints the number in waitTime using one ore more digits as needed.

This doesn't 100% explain the "both digits end up in the same place" symptom, since I'd expect random junk to be printed instead. But I'm pretty certain this is a problem, perhaps there's more problems :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however when I use `lcd.write(waitTime)` I get the DEC value and `lcd.print(waitTime)`gives me the ASCII i.e.. 49 for 1 etc.